# how to set the scale center when using UIPinchGestureRecognizer?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, gesture, uipinchgesturerecognizer

I use the code in follow to do the scaling

```
 CGAffineTransform currentTransform = self.imageView.transform;
 CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, sl, sl);
 [self.imageView setTransform:newTransform];
```

,but i found it scales around the image center,is there any methods that i can use to make it scales around my touch center?

Comment: I add the following codes to set the anchorPoint to archive this,but it works not so accurate.

Comment: CGPoint p1 = [sender locationOfTouch: 0 inView:self.imageView];
            CGPoint p2 = [sender locationOfTouch: 1 inView:self.imageView];
            
            CGPoint newCenter = CGPointMake( (p1.x+p2.x)/2,(p1.y+p2.y)/2);
            [self setAnchorPoint:CGPointMake(newCenter.x/self.imageView.bounds.size.width, newCenter.y/self.imageView.bounds.size.height) forView:self.imageView];

Comment: - (void)setAnchorPoint:(CGPoint)anchorPoint forView:(UIView *)view
{
    CGPoint oldOrigin = view.frame.origin;
    view.layer.anchorPoint = anchorPoint;
    CGPoint newOrigin = view.frame.origin;
    
    CGPoint transition;
    transition.x = newOrigin.x - oldOrigin.x;
    transition.y = newOrigin.y - oldOrigin.y;
    
    view.center = CGPointMake (view.center.x - transition.x, view.center.y - transition.y);
}